# Object Search in TS Unit Tests

Tags: palantir-foundry

I'm trying write a unit test that:
(a) creates a number of objects of different types & links between those objects
(b) passes two object sets (made up of the mocked objects) into a function and validates the output

My code generally looks like:

```
import {
    MyFunctionLibrary
} from '../src/subfolder/file'

myFunctionLibrary = new MyFunctionLibrary()

test("do something", async () => {


    const x1 = Objects.create().xType("x1")
    const x2 = Objects.create().xType("x2")

    const y = Objects.create().zType("y")
    y.links.add(x1)
    y.links.add(x2)

    console.log(Objects.search().yType().all())
    console.log(await Objects.search().yType().allAsync())

    myFunctionsLibrary.doSomething(
         Objects.search().yType(), // OS1
         Objects.search().xType() // OS2
    )
})
```

The code fails on an error in `doSomething` that checks that its first parameter (OS1) has exactly 1 object. Instead, the value of the first parameter's value is `undefined`. This is confirmed with the two console.logs

Confirmed with documentation at https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/unit-test-stub-objects/ that you should be able to just create objects like normal.

N.B. Also tried mocking the results of a filter with the `withObjectSet` function. However, I really need the inputs to be ObjectSets and not arrays, so I couldn't mock the `.take` function.

Comment: peanut galery. Since this is all javascript in the end, couldn't you just mock it with a literal object. i.e.: `{ search: () => { take: () => ["whatever you need to return"] }}` ? You can also return something that looks like an ObjectSet but isn't.